# Converting bytearray output to string without value changing in java

Tags: java, hash, arrays

I have a byte[] array named byteval in java and if I do System.out.println(byteval), I can read: d3e1547c254ff7cec8dbcef2262b5cf10ec079c7[B@40d150e0

Now I need this what I read there as a string, but if I try to convert it with Byte.toString or a new string constuctor, the value is not the same, most there are some numbers instead.

So how can I get the byte[] array as a String called strval, also cutting off the [B@40d150e0?

Now: System.out.println(byteval)>> d3e1547c254ff7cec8dbcef2262b5cf10ec079c7[B@40d150e0

Goal: System.out.println(strval)>> d3e1547c254ff7cec8dbcef2262b5cf10ec079c7

Lot of thanks!
Danny

**EDIT: Working solution for me:**

```
byte[] byteval = getValue();
// Here System.out.println(byteval) is 
// d3e1547c254ff7cec8dbcef2262b5cf10ec079c7[B@40d150e0

BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(1, byteval);
String strval = bi.toString(16);

if ((strval.length() % 2) != 0) {
    strval = "0" + strval;
}

System.out.println(strval);
// Here the String output is
// d3e1547c254ff7cec8dbcef2262b5cf10ec079c7
```

Thank all answerer.

Comment: I assume you are using `System.out.println(array[0]);` and not just literally trying to output the array

Comment: No Mr D, I do sysout with the hole array, not only one index. And this shows me the value, what I need, but i can't get it as string.

Comment: and the value of `array[0] == d3e1547c254ff7cec8dbcef2262b5cf10ec079c7`?

Comment: `System.out.println(byteval)` prints out `[B@40d150e0`. `d3e1547c254ff7cec8dbcef2262b5cf10ec079c7` must be printed somewhere else. Remove `System.out.println(byteval)` and see what happened.

Comment: Mr D, in array[0] is d3e1547c254ff7cec8dbcef2262b5cf10ec079c7-45. But it doesn't help me so much, because it's even a byte and i need it in a string var. How do I get array[0] in a string? String strval = array[0].toString() is not available and String.ValueOf(array[0]) and new String(array[0], 'UTF-8') doesn't make it

Answer (score 0):

just do

```
System.out.println(byteval.toString())
```

instead of

```
System.out.println(byteval)
```

this will remove the ending part(Actually that is just the address of the object referenced)

Comment: I don't think he meant that byteval was actually the name of his variable

Comment: he says in the beginning: 'I have a byte[] array named byteval'

Comment: both lines of you has the same output, with the address at the end

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String str= new String(byteval, "ISO-8859-1");
System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: This outputs some crypted symbols: ÓáT|%O÷ÎÈÛÎò&+\ñÀyÇ